# SQL - How to apply limit on the number of the Groups?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-spanner

In Spanner, I have a query like following ;

```
SELECT *
FROM Objects
WHERE EntityType = 0
GROUP BY EntityId
ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This query only returns 5 item in the response.
But I don't want 5 item in result.
What I wanted to get is, 5 Groups that are created upon EntityId.
So I want to get the 5 Groups under EntityId, being able to paginate through it.

Suppose that I have a table like following ;

| EntityId | EntityType | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | foo |
| 1 | 0 | bar |
| 1 | 0 | foo2 |
| 2 | 0 | bar2 |
| 1 | 0 | foo3 |
| 3 | 0 | bar3 |
| 2 | 0 | foo4 |
| 2 | 0 | bar4 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| .. | .. | .. |
| . | . | . |

There are infinite number of EntityID's and there will be various numbers of rows on each EntityId.

We have:

4 rows for EntityId 1,
3 rows for EntityId 2 and
1 row for EntityId 3

In my result, I want to get all the rows for each EntityId in a grouped manner.
So here is my requirements:

1 - it should be Grouped By EntityId

2 - it should contain all the rows for created on EntityId in each group

3 - I should be able to limit number of the Groups, say like 10 group

4 - I should be able to paginate over EntityId's

5 - I should be able to OrderBy EntityId

It return in result like a following schema to me:

| EntityId | EntityType | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | bar3 |
| 2 | 0 | bar2 |
| 2 | 0 | foo4 |
| 2 | 0 | bar4 |
| 1 | 0 | foo |
| 1 | 0 | bar |
| 1 | 0 | foo2 |
| 1 | 0 | foo3 |

Comment: Please update your question with some sample data and the result you want to achieve based on that data

Comment: Based on your result table, do you mean just select the EntityIds and order them? If not, can you update your result table to show the actual result you want to achieve?

Comment: @NickW done sir!
Indeed, I want the whole row. EntityId is just what I want to group them by.
I want to group them by EntityId and I want 10 groups no matter how many rows they contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with EntList as (
  SELECT DISTINCT EntityId
  FROM Objects
  LIMIT 10
)
SELECT O.*
FROM EntList E
INNER JOIN Objects O on E.EntityId = O.EntityId
ORDER BY O.EntityId
```